# Add knex.js .andWhere() is condition is true

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I have this Knex query:

```
const customerProducts = db.sequelize.knex.select([
      'CustomerProduct.id AS _id',
      'CustomerProduct.last_delivered AS _lastDelivered',
      'CustomerProduct.margin AS _margin',
      'CustomerProduct.outlier AS _outlier',
      'CustomerProduct.growth AS _growth',
      'CustomerProduct.period AS _period',
      'CustomerProduct.price AS _price',
      'CustomerProduct.active AS _active',
      'CustomerProduct.customer_id AS _customerId',
      'CustomerProduct.product_id AS _productId',
      'CustomerProduct.modified AS _modified',
      'CustomerProduct.month_value AS _monthValue',
      'customer.id AS _customer_id',
      'customer.title AS _customer_title',
      'customer.code AS _customer_code',
    ])
      .from('customer_products AS CustomerProduct')
      .innerJoin(
        'customers AS customer',
        'CustomerProduct.customer_id',
        'customer.id',
      )
      .where(whereClause)
      .limit(limit)
      .offset(offset);
```

I want to include an `.andWhere()` option which only gets added to the query if this condition is met:

```
if (overdue === 'true')
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const query = db.sequelize.knex.select([
      'CustomerProduct.id AS _id',
      'CustomerProduct.last_delivered AS _lastDelivered',
      'CustomerProduct.margin AS _margin',
      'CustomerProduct.outlier AS _outlier',
      'CustomerProduct.growth AS _growth',
      'CustomerProduct.period AS _period',
      'CustomerProduct.price AS _price',
      'CustomerProduct.active AS _active',
      'CustomerProduct.customer_id AS _customerId',
      'CustomerProduct.product_id AS _productId',
      'CustomerProduct.modified AS _modified',
      'CustomerProduct.month_value AS _monthValue',
      'customer.id AS _customer_id',
      'customer.title AS _customer_title',
      'customer.code AS _customer_code',
    ])
      .from('customer_products AS CustomerProduct')
      .innerJoin(
        'customers AS customer',
        'CustomerProduct.customer_id',
        'customer.id',
      );
if (overdue === 'true') {
  query = query.where(whereClause)
}
const customerProducts = query.limit(limit).offset(offset);
```

Comment: I had actually tired that but got `uncaughtException: await is only valid in async function`. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @runnerpaul You're using `await` in a function that is not declared as `async` (eg: `async function something() {.....}`).